# Most efficient algorithm to neutralize all positive and negative

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

So I've been lately working on an app which requires me to code this algorithm. But I'm unsure what I've come up with is the most efficient algorithm.

Say I have 2 sets (or rather arrays, as there can be duplicates) A and B with all positive values in A and all negative values in B.

Ex -

A = {1, 3, 1} (sum = 5)

B = {-2, -3} (sum = -5)

The sum of all elements in both the array will always be 0 (-5 + 5 = 0). The number of elements might be different.

Now what is the most efficient way (minimum steps) to neutralize all values? For example one way:

-3 + 1 = -2

Now A looks like: {0, 3, 1} and B looks like: {-2, -2}

Then -2 + 3 = 1

Now A looks like: {0, 1, 1} and B looks like {0, -2}

Now doing 2 more steps. Hence total of 4 steps. Can I compute the most efficient solution for this? How?

My take was to neutralize first the exact matching values (makes 2 elements 0 directly). Then look for biggest in positive and start merging with biggest in negative as long as possible. But it is just intuitive thinking from my side. Is there any efficient algorithm to this?

Comment: This feels like a variation on the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) which is hard.  You achieve the minimum number of steps by finding the maximum number of disjoint groups that sum to zero as the number of steps is just the sum of the numbers of elements of A and B less the number of final groups.

Comment: @RossMillikan so technically you are saying bruteforcing the best solution?

Comment: I don't know.  I just saw another way to get the number of steps that might help your thinking.  Your greedy approach of finding matching numbers seems like a good one.  I don't have an answer or I would have posted it.

Comment: I'm actually a little confused on the algorithm you're using to "neutralize"-- could you provide a little more detail for the examples?

Comment: What's wrong with "spreading": (1,3,1), (-2,-2).  2 = 2*1 so (1,1,0) = (2,0) so reduce to (0,1,1)(0,-2).  2+2*1 so so (0,1,1) = (0,2) so (0,0,0), (0,0).  Two steps?  (3,4,8,4)(5,2,6,2,1,3)->(0,2,8,4)(0,2,6,2,1,3)->(0,0,8,4)(0,0,6,2,1,3)->(0,0,0,4)(0,0,0,0,1,3)->(0,0,0,0)(0,0,0,0,0,0).

Comment: I'm not sure what counts as a step.  Removing term by term seems as efficient as any can be when compared with the steps of looking and comparing and storing then doing multple neutralizing.  I think (1,3,1)(-2,-3) note 2 = 1+1 so (0,2,1)(0,-3) not 3 = 2+1 so (0,0,0)(0,0) is as efficient as possible (3,4,8,4)(5,2,6,2,1,3) ->(0,2,8,4)(0,2,6,2,1,3)-> (0,0,8,4)(0,0,6,2,1,3)->(0,0,0,4)(0,0,0,0,1,3)->(0,0,0,0,)(0,0,0,0,0,0)

Comment: @fleablood I cannot spread. I've trimmed a lot of details here about the logic of the app. I need to actually record how many manipulations are done to every number in the list, but that's not the question here.

Comment: I think you have trimmed too many details. It's not at all clear what exactly is allowed and what is not allowed, nor how to decide which of two algorithms is more "efficient."

Comment: @DavidK minimum number of steps is the most efficient one. If the number of steps are same for 2 procedures, any one is fine.

Comment: To check I've understood the question: you have a multiset ($A \cup B$) with a total sum of zero; each step consists of removing two elements from the multiset and replacing them with their sum; and you want to minimise the number of steps required to leave only zeroes?

Comment: @PeterTaylor exactly

Comment: @PeterTaylor one more thing, in every step positive should be combined only with negative

Comment: @barrycarter I'm just picking one number from first set and another from other set. I add those up. If the result is positive, I push the positive number back to positive set and if result is negative I push it back to negative. If it's 0, then we're good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next algorithm can be used.

$(1)$Let us find the opposite pairs.

At first, to sort arrays $A$ and $B$. The directs of moving will be of modules decreasing.
If the sum of elements in the current pair is positive, use the next $A,$ else the next $B.$

$A = (3,1,1), B = (-3,-2) \rightarrow A=(1,1),\ B = (-2).$

*Note.*
The classical knapsack problem remains, requiring a search of variants. Nevertheless, one of the best strategies is "greedy" bust.
So...

$(2)$ Repeat both of cycles in arrays. If the sum of the current elements are positive, it must be saved in new array A', otherwise in new B'. Used elements must be deleted.

Results:

$A=(1,1),\ B = (-2) \rightarrow A=(1),\ B=(),\ B' = (-1).$

$(3)$ Merge $A = A \cup A',\quad B = B \cup B',$ then go to $(1).$

**In details**

Let $A=(3,2,1),\ B=(-4,-2),$\ then:
$$(1):\quad A_0+B_0 < 0\rightarrow A_0+B_1>0\rightarrow A_1+B_1 = 0\dots\rightarrow A=(3,1),\ B=(-4).$$
$$(2): A_0+B_0=-1\rightarrow A=(1),\ B=(), B'=(-1).$$
$$(3): A=(1),\ B=(-1).$$
$$(1): A_0+B_0=0\rightarrow \text{done!}$$

Comment: " If the sum of current elements are positive, use the next A,A, else the next B." Consider A = { 3, 2, 1 } B = { -4, -2 } Now you're saying that 3 - 5 is negative so I should jump to -1. Now 3-1 is positive so I jump to +1. Now 1-2 is negative. Where do I go? Also I'm not really familiar with the knapsack problem. I tried googling it but can't link it to my problem. Please elaborate your point 2 as well

Comment: @MehulMohan Was vaguely worded. Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: @MehulMohan The example parsing is added

Comment: can you read last paragraph in the question? Isn't that exactly the same thing you've proposed in the last 4 steps? Please let me know

Comment: @MehulMohan Let us check our terms. Summation in $(1)$ is only a checking of the opposite pairs to delete, and summation in (2) is the step of the "greedy" algorythm in the knapsack task, isn't it?

Comment: I'll implement this. Thanks

Comment: @MehulMohan Interesting task. Thank you too

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer.

If I understood correctly, the only valid operation is picking one element from A and one element from B, computing their sum, then inserting the result and 0 where appropriate. Repeat until both sets are all 0s.

Then, in every step, you replace either 1 or 2 numbers with 0 (zero). So, at best you can do about size-of-one-set operations, and at most size(A)+size(B) operations. Linear.

How much better are you looking for, and why? How costly are the operations?

Update: How you assign costs to operations, and what it is you want to minimize is important. For example, walking through both sets [for example, say, put each on a stack, etc.] and "neutralizing" pairs as you see them would cost O(size(A)+size(B)), but just sorting both sets costs a factor of log() more.

Comment: The problems is not about the cost of applying the list of operations, it's to find a minimal length list (or a possibly easier version is to decide if a given list is minimal).